# Avoid getting duplicate values from BlockingCollection with seperate threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, duplicates

I'm receiving data at around 50 Hz from a historian database. I want to stream this out the other end around 10 Hz.
To achieve this I spawn two timers, one for getting data from the historian database (I run this twice as fast as the sending timer). A second timer which is 200ms (10 Hz). 
The first timer stores every value it gets in a BlockingCollection (I tried a ConcurrentQueue aswell). I can’t use a normal list/queue due to two different threads reading/writing to the collection. 
The challenge with this is that it doesn’t give me an even 50Hz. I expect to get around 5 values for every call, but it gives me data in bursts (i.e. sometimes nothing, sometimes 15). I therefore have the BlockingCollection as a buffer which the sending timer gets data from.
The sending timer uses a recursive method to get the data in the middle of the list. It checks if the value is sent, gets the next 5th value if it already is (50Hz -> 10Hz), if not send the value.
Now to the problem; the recursive method sometimes sends the same value twice, even though I lock the object. We’ve pinpointed the issue to be that the locking isn’t working as intended, but we have no idea why, or how to solve it.

Any suggestions?
The code attached isn’t the true code, but it illustrates the problem, and actually gives you duplicate values, although not very often.

```
class Program {

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, BlockingCollection<TestObject>> _pipes = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, BlockingCollection<TestObject>>();
    private const int Interval = 5;

    private Timer inTimer;
    private Timer outTimer;

    static void Main() {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.Run();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void Run() {
        _pipes[100] = new BlockingCollection<TestObject>();
        _pipes[200] = new BlockingCollection<TestObject>();
        _pipes[300] = new BlockingCollection<TestObject>();

        inTimer = new Timer(InTimer, null, 0, 100);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        outTimer = new Timer(OutTimer, null, 0, 200);
    }

    private void OutTimer(object state) {
        foreach (TestObject testObject in GetNotSentTestObjects()) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2}", testObject.PipeId, testObject.Timestamp.ToString("o"), testObject.Value);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<TestObject> GetNotSentTestObjects() {
        List<TestObject> testObjects = new List<TestObject>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, BlockingCollection<TestObject>> pipe in _pipes) {
            TestObject testObject = GetLatestTestObjectNotSent(pipe.Key, (pipe.Value.Count / 2));
            if (testObject == null) {
                return null;
            }
            testObjects.Add(testObject);
        }
        return testObjects;
    }

    private TestObject GetLatestTestObjectNotSent(int key, int locationInList) {

        BlockingCollection<TestObject> pipe = _pipes[key];
        TestObject testObject;
        lock (pipe) {
            testObject = pipe.ElementAt(locationInList - 1);

            if (testObject.Sent) {
                int nextLocationInList = locationInList + Interval;
                GetLatestTestObjectNotSent(key, nextLocationInList);
            }
            testObject.Sent = true;
        }
        testObject.PipeId = key;
        return testObject;
    }

    private void InTimer(object sender) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(0,20); i++) {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, BlockingCollection<TestObject>> pipe in _pipes) {
                pipe.Value.Add(new TestObject());
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

internal class TestObject {
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Sent { get; set; }
    public int PipeId;

    public TestObject() {
        Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Note, the Thread.Sleep is to let the lists be populated. In my code I also have code to trim the lists after a while.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use [BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) to read from it?

Comment: You should know that `Thread.Sleep(1000)` makes your thread sleep for at least 1 second, but it may sleep for 2 or 3 or whatever seconds the OS decides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of head bashing it turns out I need to return when i use the recursive method...

Answer (score 2):

A `BlockingCollection` is a queue. It's not designed for random access, and trying to randomly access it is going to cause you no end of trouble. You're also not removing items from the queue, which means that eventually you're going to run out of memory.

One problem you might be having is that, although you're locking the list when you access it with `ElementAt`, you're not locking it when you add items. But the whole idea of locking a concurrent data structure ought to make you reconsider your design. You shouldn't ever have to lock a concurrent data structure.

As I understand it, you want to pick every 5th item that hasn't yet been processed. That turns out to be a rather difficult problem if you don't want to discard unprocessed items (i.e. items 1-4). If you were to discard those items, then it's a simple matter of calling `Take` five times:

```
TestObject o;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    o = pipe.Take();
}
// You now have the 5th item from the queue
// The other items have been discarded
```

If you want to keep those items around for possible processing later, you have to add them back to the queue somehow. But they'll go to the end of the queue, which means that you'll process older items before newer ones.

Also, at some point you're going to fill up the queue because the producer is adding things faster than they're being consumed.

You need to give some more thought to how you want this application to work, or do a better job of explaining it to us. What you've described and the code you've posted are ... confused, and make it impossible for us to give good recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Same thread can acquire the same lock many times. See this example

```
object o = new object();
lock (o) lock (o) Console.WriteLine("Acquired lock two times");
```

You should use other synchronization primitives like Mutex, Semaphore, AutoResetEvent etc...